# The ImageView displays the image only if set to background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying to load a bitmap to an `ImageView`.
If I do:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);  
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Nothing is displayed.
If I do:

```
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"
```

The image is displayed.
My activity `extends AppCompatActivity` and my layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what type of drawable resource is myimage?

Comment: @smitty1: Actually I just saw that the `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage)` returns `null`. I tried even the android's drawable (e.g `ic_launcher_foreground`) didn't work (also returns null)

Comment: @smitty1: The `myimage` is vector drawable

Comment: This won't work if trying to convert vector to bitmap. You need to use canvas.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi: How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't convert a vector graphic directly to bitmap.  You have to create a bitmap from a drawable and then draw it to a canvas

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

I you have used  vector drawable and try to set this drawable programmatically‎ in imageView .so, use this code to set vector drawable programmatically‎ :

**First Way**

```
 image_view=findViewById(R.id.image_view);
      image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_send);
```

**Second Way**

```
image_view=findViewById(R.id.image_view);

  Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_send);

  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
  drawable.draw(canvas);
  image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your drawable file should not be vector. 
if drawable is vector then use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_file"`
otherwise you can use `android:src="@drawable/your_file"`

and try to set Image like this 
`image_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_send);`

Comment: app:srcCompat is only required when working with pre 21 api.